# decltype(auto) vs auto&& to conserve cv qualifier

Tags: c++11, c++14

Is there an advantage to use the c++14 feature decltype(auto) vs auto&& for keeping cv qualifier ?

```
auto v = const_return_func() //strip the constness
auto&& v = const_return_func()
decltype(auto) = const_return_func()
```

Comment: All three forms serve different purposes - `auto` is *always* a value, `auto&&` is *always* a reference, and `decltype(auto)` can be either, depending on the initializer.

Comment: Please open a new question instead of appending to this one and changing the title. If you click "edit", you can rollback to a previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the function returns a `const &` reference, since `const` object and `const &&` are fairly useless return types, `decltype(auto)` will do the same thing as `auto &&`.

You should generally not use `decltype(auto)` for local variables as it has no particular use case, and obscures whether the declared entity is an object or a reference.